# PHP Define() - Building Its Value Parameter with Multiple Parts

Tags: php, parameters

Can the value of PHP's `define()` be constructed ...

1. Like this: `define(MY_NEW_CONSTANT, "He" + "llo - " + "World");`
2. Like this: `define(MY_NEW_CONSTANT, "He", "llo - ", "World");`
3. Like this: `define(MY_NEW_CONSTANT, "He" + "llo - " + $One_Of_My_Variables);`
4. Like this: `define(MY_NEW_CONSTANT, "He", "llo - ", $One_Of_My_Variables);`

How does one build the value parameter within PHP's `define()` - is it possible?

Comment: `.` is the concatenation operator in PHP, not `+`.

Comment: The time it took you to write this post is probably longer than the time it would took you to just search it on google.

Comment: Actually, the matter was indeed first searched via Google.  Several PHP sites were checked but none showed building the value parameter.  As you may have already guessed, I am not a PHP programmer.

Answer (score 1):

You concatenate with the concatenation operator, `.`:

```
define('MY_NEW_CONSTANT', "He" . "llo - " . "World");
```

[`define`](http://php.net/define) is just a function like any other; it doesn't have special rules in terms of what expressions you can pass it.

Comment: Gracious you are quick to reply - thank you. What if the value needs to have the "(" and ")" characters.  For example, the value parameter needs to include (Something Like This)

Comment: @user1367880: Makes absolutely no difference in the value. Strings can contain anything.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this, but it's a bad idea. The point of a constant is that it's.... ehm... constant. You know, like, always the same value.

If you define a constant with a dynamic value like this, then it's basically just another global variable. Granted it's a variable you can't change later in the program, but that doesn't change the fact that you may just as well have used a global variable.

PHP also supports `const`, which can be considered a newer replacement for `define()`. `const` does not allow dynamic construction of constants for exactly the reasons above.

If you still really want to do it, just concatenate your strings inside the `define()` function, as you would to pass a string to any other function call. ie:

```
define('MYCONST', $var1 . $var2);
```

But I suggest using variables instead.